# Regex to replace url with a word python

Tags: python, regex, url

I am trying to replace few urls in a long string.

A sample here:

```
s = 'https://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Alberta/Edmonton/MNS-Enterprise-\nLtd/8114324.html, https://411.ca/business/profile/13300641'
```

Due to the newline character within the url, the match will always stop at `\n`.
I tried

```
re.sub(r'(https?://[\S]*)', 'website__', s, re.DOTALL)
```

but the result breaks at `\n`

```
'website__\nLtd/8114324.html, website__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `\n` and use

```py
re.sub(r'https?://[\n\S]+\b', '<URL>', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9gShDC/1). *Details*:

- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `[\n\S]+` - one or more newline or non-whitespace chars
- `\b` - until the rightmost word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5jAPl4):

```py
import re
s = 'https://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Alberta/Edmonton/MNS-Enterprise-\nLtd/8114324.html, https://411.ca/business/profile/13300641'
print( re.sub(r'https?://[\n\S]+\b', 'website__', s) )
# => website__, website__
```